# React "appendChild" appends node BELOW div instead of within?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to embed a Calendly app in my React app. I have a `div` that I would like to embed it within because I would like to give the Calendly app a `width` and `height`, which I was planning to do by styling the `div` tag; otherwise, it appears super small with a scroll bar.

In order to run the Javascript to embed the Calendly app, I have to create the node and append it to the DOM. When I do this, it seems to get added *below* my target `div` as you can see in this screenshot (which I labeled for clarity's sake):
[image]

I tried to put together a CodeSandbox for this post, but *it works as expected there*: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-df8ns. Why is this working on the CodeSandbox but not locally?

**EDIT:**

I'd like to clarify my response to Junius' comment. There is in fact a way for me to embed Calendly without modifying the DOM directly (see below). However, using that methodology seems to prevent me from passing in the "prefill" parameter. I would happily use that methodology if I could pass in that parameter, but I haven't figured out how to do so.

```
.
.
.

render(){
    return (
        <div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/username" style={{"min-width":"320px","height":"780px"}} />
    );
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't modify the dom directly.

Comment: @JuniusL. I would rather not, but there doesn't seem to be an alternative way to embed the Calendly app...

Comment: How do you need to pass the prefill parameter? As in what should the expected output HTML look like

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to pass in query string parameters to the URL by looking at the output:

```
.
.
.
render(){
    const data_url = `https://calendly.com/username?name=${this.props.firstName}%20${this.props.lastName}&email=${this.props.email}`
    return (
        <div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url={data_url} style={{"min-width":"320px","height":"780px"}} />
    );
}
```